# Updating schema for one entity without deleting everything else

Tags: doctrine-orm

When I run a schema update it successfully updates the schemas for my entities, but if there are any 'non-doctrine' tables in the database it deletes them.  Unfortunately, these other tables are required for the 3rd party CMS I'm using.

Is there a way to tell doctrine to update the schema for certain entities (or all of them) without deleting anything else?

Below is my existing update code.  The `$classes` array contains all the meta data for entity classes found in several different plugins.

```
//$em is an instance of EntityManager

//Psuedo Code
$classes = array(
     $em->getClassMetadata('class1'),
     $em->getClassMetadata('class2'),
     $em->getClassMetadata('class3'),
     $em->getClassMetadata('class4'),
     $em->getClassMetadata('class5'),
);

//Real Code
$st = new Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool( $em );
if ($classes)
    $st->updateSchema($classes);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gets all of the update sql but parses out any drop statements:

```
$sql = $st->getUpdateSchemaSql( $classes );

$count = count($sql);
for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)
{
    if(substr($sql[$i], 0, 4) == 'DROP')
        unset($sql[$i]);
}

foreach($sql as $statement)
{
    $em->getConnection()->exec( $statement );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could run the schema tool with `--dump-sql` instead of `--force`, copy and paste the output from `--dump-sql` and run it on your database manually (of course removing the `DROP` statements for the tables you want to preserve.)